# tensorflow : - import tensorflow as tf throwing error module not found in windows using native pip

Tags: tensorflow, pip

I have installed Python 3 and pip 9.0.1. I have installed TensorFlow using the command

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Now I am trying to import TensorFlow as tf using command

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

But I am getting an error that there is no module name TensorFlow. I am using native pip.

Can you please help on this.

Comment: Have you checked the list of common installation problems [on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#common_installation_problems)? If none of those helps, please include the full error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First you should type `activate tensorflow`, then something like the following will appear:

```
<tensorflow> C:\Users\My Computer>
```

Now type `python`, and then type the following in the Python prompt:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

I hope it might be useful...